# 2 dimensional table query with join and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pivot, inner-join

Trying to return a 2 dimensional table from SQL query (Postgres). Read about Pivot Table (but not sure if it is valid for join) and crosstab/tablefunc but no luck.

Expected result

```
            App A | App B
2020-01-01  8     | 2
2020-02-01  14    | 5
2020-03-01  13    | 0
```

I have 2 tables:

- applications: name
- orders: date, ...

I'm looking to count orders by month and application.

My attempt so far.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', date) as date, count(1), x.name
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month', date) as date, application_id
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY date, application_id) o
JOIN applications x ON o.application_id = x.id AND x.id in (1, 2, 5)  
WHERE
  o.date > NOW() - '9 months'::interval
group by date, x.name
order by date, x.name
```

which returns

```
date        count name
2020-01-01  8     App A
2020-01-01  2     App B
2020-02-01  14    App A
2020-02-01  5     App B
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pivot your resultset over a fixed list of values, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', o.date) date,
    count(*) filter(where a.name = 'App A') app_a,
    count(*) filter(where a.name = 'App B') app_b
from applications a
inner join orders o on o.application_id = a.id
where o.date > date_trunc('month', current_date) - '9 months'::interval
group by 1
order by 1
```

Note that I modified the `where` clause so it filters on entire months.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gmb. Solved. Can you please edit your answer to read `o.application_id = a.id`